# mysql query to sort some results but join data may or not be present

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT PLD_LINK.ID, PLD_LINK.TITLE, PLD_LINK.URL, PLD_CATEGORY.TITLE, TLL_SORT_STATUS.status, PLD_LINK_COMMENT.DATE_ADDED
    FROM PLD_LINK, PLD_CATEGORY, TLL_SORT_STATUS, PLD_LINK_COMMENT 
    WHERE PLD_LINK.CATEGORY_ID = PLD_CATEGORY.ID 
        AND PLD_LINK.ID = TLL_SORT_STATUS.link_id 
        AND PLD_LINK.PAGERANK BETWEEN -1 AND 2
        AND PLD_LINK.CATEGORY_ID IN (1291,2113,2664)
        ORDER BY COUNT(PLD_LINK.ID = PLD_LINK_COMMENT.LINK_ID) ASC
```

This is my query. I would like to get all the results that match before ORDER BY. Now, some of the id's from PLD_LINK.ID may be in the table PLD_LINK_COMMENT but some may not be. SO when mysql reaches ORDER BY i would like to order the results in an ascending order based on the following criteria: the id's that are not in PLD_LINK_COMMENT should be the first and following after that the ones's that are based on the number of comments per ID. (an ID can have none, 1, 2 ... comments.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an outer join between the three main tables and PLD_LINK_COMMENT.

The outer join will mean you get a null for the PLD_LINK_COMMENT.LINK_ID, which means that the COUNT will return 0 for a PLD_LINK.ID with no matching link comments, and the appropriate number of comments for the others.

You need to group by the non-aggregated columns...but that then shows that M.Date_Added probably isn't what you want to GROUP BY; and the question/answer in the comments shows that we need the most recent comment date, or some preposterously early data like '0001-01-01' (the earliest valid date in SQL) or '0000-00-00' (a pseudo-date used by MySQL).

Hence:

```
SELECT K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.Status,
       MAX(NVL(M.Date_Added, DATE '0001-01-01')) AS MostRecentComment
  FROM Pld_Link AS K JOIN Pld_Category AS C ON K.Category_ID = C.ID
       JOIN Tll_Sort_Status AS C ON K.ID = S.Link_ID
       OUTER JOIN Pld_Link_Comment AS M ON K.ID = M.Link_ID
 WHERE K.PageRank BETWEEN -1 AND 2
   AND K.Category_ID IN (1291,2113,2664)
 GROUP BY K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.Status
 ORDER BY COUNT(M.Link_ID) ASC
```

You also need your DBMS (MySQL you said) to allow you to order by columns that are not listed in the SELECT-list.

---

### Tested SQL

Tested using IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50 on MacOS X 10.6.2.  I've used `DATE('0001-01-01')` because IDS has a function called DATE that requires parentheses, and I used '0001-01-01' because IDS does not recognize '0000-00-00' as a valid date.

```
SELECT K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.STATUS,
       MAX(NVL(M.Date_Added, DATE('0001-01-01'))) AS MostRecentComment,
  FROM PLD_Link AS K JOIN PLD_Category AS C ON K.Category_ID = C.ID
       JOIN Tll_Sort_Status AS S ON K.ID = S.Link_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PLD_Link_Comment AS M ON K.ID = M.Link_ID
 WHERE K.PageRank BETWEEN -1 AND 2
   AND K.Category_ID IN (1291,2113,2664)
 GROUP BY K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.STATUS
 ORDER BY COUNT(M.Link_ID)
```

Result:

```
id  title                 url                       title   status  mostrecent
4   #4: This should show  example.com/?id=4;c=2113  Cat 2113  0  0001-01-01
3   #3: This should show  example.com/?id=3;c=1291  Cat 1291 -1  2010-03-10
7   #7: This should show  example.com/?id=7;c=2664  Cat 2664  3  2010-07-11
5   #5: This should show  example.com/?id=5;c=2113  Cat 2113  1  2010-05-17
2   #2: This should show  example.com/?id=2;c=1291  Cat 1291 -2  2010-02-13
```

Alternative, selecting the comment count, to show that the data is presented in the correct order.

```
SELECT K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.STATUS,
       MAX(NVL(M.Date_Added, DATE('0001-01-01'))) AS MostRecentComment,
       COUNT(M.Link_ID) AS CommentCount
  FROM PLD_Link AS K JOIN PLD_Category AS C ON K.Category_ID = C.ID
       JOIN Tll_Sort_Status AS S ON K.ID = S.Link_ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN PLD_Link_Comment AS M ON K.ID = M.Link_ID
 WHERE K.PageRank BETWEEN -1 AND 2
   AND K.Category_ID IN (1291,2113,2664)
 GROUP BY K.ID, K.Title, K.URL, C.Title, S.STATUS
 ORDER BY CommentCount ASC;
```

Result set:

```
id title                 url                       title  status  recent  count
4  #4: This should show  example.com/?id=4;c=2113  Cat 2113  0  0001-01-01  0
3  #3: This should show  example.com/?id=3;c=1291  Cat 1291 -1  2010-03-10  1
7  #7: This should show  example.com/?id=7;c=2664  Cat 2664  3  2010-07-11  1
5  #5: This should show  example.com/?id=5;c=2113  Cat 2113  1  2010-05-17  2
2  #2: This should show  example.com/?id=2;c=1291  Cat 1291 -2  2010-02-13  3
```

---

### Sample data base

#### PLD_Category

```
CREATE TABLE PLD_Category
(
    ID      SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PLD_Category VALUES(3961, 'Cat 3961');
INSERT INTO PLD_Category VALUES(1291, 'Cat 1291');
INSERT INTO PLD_Category VALUES(2113, 'Cat 2113');
INSERT INTO PLD_Category VALUES(2664, 'Cat 2664');
```

#### PLD_Link

```
CREATE TABLE PLD_Link
(
    ID          SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Category_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES PLD_Category,
    Title       VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PageRank    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    URL         VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(1, 3961, '#1: This should not',  0, 'example.com/?id=1;c=3961');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(2, 1291, '#2: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=2;c=1291');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(3, 1291, '#3: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=3;c=1291');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(4, 2113, '#4: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=4;c=2113');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(5, 2113, '#5: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=5;c=2113');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(6, 3961, '#6: This should not',  0, 'example.com/?id=6;c=3961');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(7, 2664, '#7: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=7;c=2664');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link
    VALUES(8, 2664, '#8: This should show', 0, 'example.com/?id=8;c=2664');
```

#### TLL_Sort_Status

```
CREATE TABLE TLL_Sort_Status
(
    STATUS      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    Link_ID     INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES PLD_Link
);

INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(-3, 1);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(-2, 2);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(-1, 3);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES( 0, 4);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(+1, 5);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(+2, 6);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(+3, 7);
INSERT INTO TLL_Sort_Status VALUES(+4, 1);
```

#### PLD_Link_Comment

```
CREATE TABLE PLD_Link_Comment
(
    Link_ID     INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES PLD_Link,
    Date_Added  DATE NOT NULL,
    COMMENT     VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(1, DATE('2010-01-11'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(2, DATE('2010-02-11'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(2, DATE('2010-02-12'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(2, DATE('2010-02-13'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(3, DATE('2010-03-10'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(5, DATE('2010-05-15'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(5, DATE('2010-05-17'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(6, DATE('2010-06-10'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(6, DATE('2010-06-12'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(6, DATE('2010-06-14'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(6, DATE('2010-06-19'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(7, DATE('2010-07-11'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(8, DATE('2010-08-12'), 'Vacuous comment');
INSERT INTO PLD_Link_Comment VALUES(8, DATE('2010-08-13'), 'Vacuous comment');
```

Comment: if the COUNT value is 0 can I set the value for DATE_ADDED to 0000-00-00 in the sql query?

Comment: In MySQL, probably; in other DBMS, no - 0000-00-00 isn't a valid date.  You'd probably use the NVL or COALESCE functions: `NVL(M.Date_Added, DATE '0000-00-00')`.

Comment: @user253530: Suppose there are three comments for a PLD_LINK entry with three different dates; which date should be shown - oldest, newest, something else?

Comment: ok, since the question i asked is part of a bigger problem can you help me with this: i have search patterns, variable number of search patterns, which i want to find in the PLD_LINK.TITLE OR PLD_LINK.URL. I need to perform that query to return me only the results that match those search patterns (and in the same time those other conditions have to be satisfied)

Comment: That complicates life.  With Informix, I'd put the search patterns into a temporary table (call it SearchPatterns, with a single column Pattern), and then add a condition along the lines of: `AND K.Link_ID IN (SELECT K2.Link_ID FROM PLD_Link AS K2 CROSS JOIN SearchPatterns AS P WHERE K2.Title LIKE P.Pattern OR K2.URL LIKE P.Pattern)`.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. You helped me more than i would have expected.

Comment: @user253350: The preferred way of saying 'thank you' is an upvote and/or an 'accept' vote.